# "Object doesn't support this property or method IE" error in Javascript possibly from using hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, for-in-loop, hasownproperty

I'm getting this error in IE8 and IE7 for some reason. I'm looping through all keys within my object and it keeps telling me `Object doesn't support this property or method` on this on:

```
var inVal = $(inType + "#" + inName).val().trim();
```

The entire block is below:

```
for (var key in inputs) { // find all keys "brand", "name", etc. in our inputs object
        var errors = false;

        if (inputs.hasOwnProperty(key)) { // focus on our obj. not all others on page 
            var inType = inputs[key].inputType;
            var inName = inputs[key].inputName;
            var inVal = $(inType + "#" + inName).val().trim(); // construct input field

            if (inVal == '' || inVal == null) {
                errors = true;

                $('#' + inName + '-error').html('');
                $('#' + inName + '-error').hide().fadeIn().html(inputs[key].errorMsg);
                $(inType + '#' + inName).focus();
                $('#modal-loadable-inner').scrollTop(inputs[key].scrollTop);

                return;
            } else { // user corrected error
                errors = false;
                $('#' + inName + '-error').html(''); // remove error txt
            }
        }
    }
```

Someone posted this on Doug Crockford's jslint boards and he responded with:

> for (key in object) {
>       if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, key)) {
>       ...
>       }
>       }
>
> hasOwnProperty should have been an operator, not a method, because
>   being a
>       method, it is prone to these sorts of problems. But it is what it is, so you
>       have to work around that.

Works fine in Chrome, FF, Safari, Opera, etc.. as usual. Any idea on a workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's caused by your `trim()` as string do not have this method.

Try this instead

```
var inVal = $.trim($(inType + "#" + inName).val());
```

Comment: I think you have it. *val* should return a string, and not all browsers have a *String.prototype.trim* method (such as IE 8).

Comment: @RobG The [jQuery `.val()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) says that it can return a "String, Number, Array". So it's not 100% correct to say that `.val()` _always_ returns a string.

Comment: Your right, it might return an array if the element is a multiple select element. It should never return a number, can you say when it does?

Answer (score 1):

`.val()` may not be returning a string, so calling `.trim()` on it is probably causing the problem. Try using an intermediate variable and checking it is not undefined before calling `.toString().trim()` on it (assuming `.trim()` is a method you added to strings in Javascript - the jQuery method is `$.trim()`).

Comment: Quincy beat you by 1 second, but thank you also for your help :)